# Power Point: How do I generate this character in mathcal?

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, addons, windows-8-fonts

(Mathcal is a font used in Latex https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:%5Cmathcal)

> I have posted the question on Tex SE and it was closed
>   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313269/how-to-use-mathcal-in-powerpoint
>
> Anyways, I am in need to generate a mathcal X instead of the scriptX
>   in power point

[image]

> Does anyone know how to generate that mathcal X character in power
>   point? Which font do I have to install or use?

Comment: what is mathcal X? please give a bit more background

Comment: why did you tagged your question as [addons], how that's related?

Comment: A mathcal X is a X generated using the Mathcal font used in Latex https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:%5Cmathcal

Comment: I tagged my question with Addon because an Addon maybe needed to interface between Latex fonts and MS fonts.

Comment: How about "Chi" in a different font? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(letter)

Comment: @Peter Hi I found a solution using the font type jsMath-cmbsy10, but the resulting character was too thick :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just type `\scriptX` (or replace `X` with any other letter you want to input) inside the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any `latex -> svg image` tool and then insert the image.

Such as https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191624)

Answer (score -2):

Nice pretty, but it works: You could make a screenshot of the character and insert the image in powerpoint

Comment: Can you elaborate on this to make it more explicit how to accomplish what was asked in the question?  Thanks.